# Band Switching Circuit

Tags: capacitor, rf, switches

I am building an oscillator circuit at 4-6 GHz and I am trying to make a band switching circuit to add capacitors up to 10pF. Every band switching diode and low capacitance transistor I have tried have not helped me so far! Which is a good component to use as a switch in my circuit and how should it be connected with the capacitor to control it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: an RF switch IC. (I know, sounds obvious in hindsight...)

Comment: you have to start with a physically small one, and then design its residual capacitance and inductance into your circuit.

Comment: Why not use a varactor diode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Companies like Skyworks have [PIN diodes](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/DDA5C4D1DE334FC682514D5BE10AE9D9.ashx) down to the sub-0.1pF range. The packages get significantly more inconvenient as you get to lower capacitances.

[Here](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/Documents/Products/1-100/Design_With_PIN_Diodes_200312D.pdf) is an application note on switch design.

[image]